# What do C++ arrays init to?

Tags: c++, memory

So I can fix this manually so it isn't an urgent question but I thought it was really strange:

Here is the entirety of my code before the weird thing that happens:

```
int main(int argc, char** arg) {

int memory[100];
int loadCounter = 0;
bool getInput = true;
print_memory(memory);
```

and then some other unrelated stuff.

The print memory just prints the array which should've initialized to all zero's but instead the first few numbers are:

+1606636544 +32767 +1606418432 +32767 +1856227894 +1212071026 +1790564758 +813168429 +0000 +0000

(the plus and the filler zeros are just for formatting since all the numbers are supposed to be from 0-1000 once the array is filled. The rest of the list is zeros)

It also isn't memory leaking because I tried initializing a different array variable and on the first run it also gave me a ton of weird numbers. Why is this happening?

Comment: C/C++ isn't like the managed languages. It (usually) doesn't zero-initialize POD arrays.

Comment: Change to `int memory[100] = { 0 };` to zero-initialize the array.

Comment: try `int memory[100] = {};`

Comment: @JonathanPotter will that initialize the entire array to 0 or just memory[0]?

Comment: who cares about those `cout`s? how are they relevant here? please post minimal code.

Comment: or make it `static` like `static int memory[100];`

Comment: Why do you expect the memory array to be filled with zeroes? Nowhere in the code is this done.

Comment: @Prime: The whole array as per 8.5.1.7.

Comment: @user1095108, Of course that would change the whole meaning, however.

Comment: I already changed it to int memory[100] = {0}. I was just asking where the random numbers came from because I was curious. @namezero because if they had to arbitrary init an empty array one would think they would use zero's or nulls rather than random variables?

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked "What do C++ arrays init to?", the answer is **they init to whatever happens to be in the memory they have been allocated** at the time they come into scope.
I.e. **they are not initialized**.

Do note that some compilers will initialize stack variables to zero in debug builds; this can lead to nasty, randomly occurring issues once you start doing release builds.

Comment: What you said applies only to POD types. If you have an array of objects that have a default constructor, such a constructor is guaranteed to be called, so the objects are initialized according to the constructor (this rule applies recursively to the data fields). Of course, if the constructor doesn't initialize some data field (which in turn doesn't have a constructor), it will be left uninitialized.

Comment: Also, at least in my experience, usually it's in *release* mode that you get all-zero stack and heap (since the memory pages that the OS gives at start are normally zeroed out for security purposes); instad, in debug mode several compilers will fill uninitialized memory with particular patterns to aid debugging.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Yes, I was talking about POD types. Of course, complex types will have the guarantee to have the constructor called. (Unless you use placement new). While some OSes do zero out pages, this is hardly something you can rely on; and even if the OS did do that, it could be that the memory was previously used within the application and hence contains garbage.

Comment: Also, iirc the VC compiles 6.0 and before initialized stack POD variables to 0 on debug builds; current VC compilers use 0xCC

Answer (score 1):

The array you are using is stack allocated:

int memory[100];

When the particular function scope exits (In this case main) or returns, the memory will be reclaimed and it will not leak. This is how stack allocated memory works. In this case you allocated 100 integers (32 bits each on my compiler) on the stack as opposed to on the heap. A heap allocation is just somewhere else in memory hopefully far far away from the stack. Anyways, heap allocated memory has a chance for leaking. Low level Plain Old Data allocated on the stack (like you wrote in your code) won't leak.

The reason you got random values in your function was probably because you didn't initialize the data in the 'memory' array of integers. In release mode the application or the C runtime (in windows at least) will not take care of initializing that memory to a known base value. So the memory that is in the array is memory left over from last time the stack was using that memory. It could be a few milli-seconds old (most likely) to a few seconds old (less likely) to a few minutes old (way less likely). Anyways, it's considered garbage memory and it's to be avoided at all costs.

The problem is we don't know what is in your function called print_memory. But if that function doesn't alter the memory in any ways, than that would explain why you are getting seemingly random values. You need to initialize those values to something first before using them. I like to declare my stack based buffers like this:

int memory[100] = {0};

That's a shortcut for the compiler to fill the entire array with zero's. 
It works for strings and any other basic data type too:

char MyName[100] = {0};
float NoMoney[100] = {0};

Not sure what compiler you are using, but if you are using a microsoft compiler with visual studio you should be just fine.

Comment: I am using xcode. I changed it to int memory[100] = {0} after I noticed this but I was just wondering where those numbers came from.

Comment: @JessicaShu, They came from undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, consider this: **What is an array?**

In managed languages, such as Java or C#, you work with high-level abstractions. C and C++ don't provide abstractions (I mean hardware abstractions, not language abstractions like OO features). They are dessigned to work *close to metal* that is, the language uses the hardware directly (Memory in this case) without abstractions.

That means when you declare a local variable, `int a` for example, what the compiler does is to say "*Ok, im going to interpret the chunk of memory `[A,A + sizeof(int)]` as an integer, which I call 'a'*" (Where A is the offset between the beginning of that chunk and the start address of function's stack frame). 
As you can see, the compiler only "assigns" memory-segments to variables. It does not do any "magic", like "creating" variables. You have to understand that **your code is executed in a machine, and the machine has only a memory and a CPU**. There is no magic.

So what is the value of a variable when the function execution starts? **The value represented with the data which the chunk of memory of the variable has**. Commonly, that data has no sense from our current point of view (Could be part of the data used previously by a string, for example), so when you access that variable you get extrange values. **Thats what we call "garbage": Data previously written which has no sense in our context.**

The same applies to an array: An array is only a bigger chunk of memory, with enough space to fit all the values of the array: `[A,A + (length of the array)*sizeof(type of array elements)]`. So as in the variable case, **the memory contains garbage**.

Commonly you want to initialize an array with a set of values during its declaration. You could achieve that using an initialiser list:

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

In that case, the compiler adds code to the function to initialize the memory-chunk which the array is with that values.

#### Sidenote: Non-POD types and static storage

The things explained above only applies to [POD types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) such as basic types and arrays of basic types. With non-POD types like classes the compiler adds calls to the constructor of the variables, which are designed to initialise the values (attributes) of a class instance.

In addition, even if you use POD types, if variables have [static storage specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), the compiler initializes its memory with a default value, because static variables are allocated at program start.

Answer (score 0):

the local variable on stack is not initialized in c/c++. c/c++ is designed to be fast so it doesn't zero stack on function calls.

Comment: I find this answer very confusing. For example, `std::string s;` would cause `s` to be on the stack and initialized. Any language that zeroed the stack on function calls would be extremely hard to use, considering all of your variables would lose their value.

Comment: i supposed zeroing stack on func call means that none initialized var would be zero while the initialed variables should not lose their value.

Answer (score 0):

Before `main()` runs, the language runtime sets up the environment. Exactly what it's doing you'd have to discover by breaking at the load module's entry point and watching the stack pointer, but at any rate your stack space on entering `main` is not guaranteed clean.

Anything that needs clean stack or `malloc` or `new` space gets to clean it itself. Plenty of things don't. C[++] isn't in the business of doing unnecessary things.  In C++ a class object can have non-trivial constructors that run implicitly, those guarantee the object's set up for use, but arrays and plain scalars don't have constructors, if you want an inital value you have to declare an initializer.